# How to delete a series of positions within a file based on a list of numbers with Bash

Tags: bash, fasta

I'm pretty new in Bash scripting and i have a problem to solve. I have a file that look like this:

```
>atac
ATTGGCAATTAAATTCTTTT
>lipa
ATTACCAAGTAAATTCTTTT
.
.
.
```

where each even lines have the same length, but can have different characters, and i need to remove, in each even lines, a series of position listed in  a .txt file. The .txt have only a list of number, one for each lines, that correspond to the positions to be removed and look like this:

```
3
5
8
10
11
```

the expected output must keep the same length for each even line, but in each of them, the positions listed in the .txt file must have been deleted. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: let's take 3 then 5, the 3rd and the 5th indicate the original string index or each step result? for example `1234567`, first remove the 3rd, we have `124567`, now the 5th would be "6".  would you in the "5" turn delete `6` or `5`? it would be good if you paste your expected output in the question, so that we know what do you really want.

Comment: I don't understand the question: what is a "position"? Is it a line number, or is it the position of a character on a line?

Comment: So you want to remove all 3rd (5th, 8th, 10th, 11th, ...) characters from all even lines from a file?

Comment: I also don't understand the question, can you show the desired result?

Comment: yes I know, i'm sorry, my only justification is that I didn't really know where to start from (apart from using awk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "position" in the `txt` file indicates always the index of the original string, this awk-oneliner will help you:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}FNR%2==0{for(x in a)$x=""}7' your.txt  FS="" OFS="" file
>atac
ATGCATAATTCTTTT
>lipa
ATACAGAATTCTTTT
```

We mark (as "`-`") the deleted char so that you can verify if the result is correct:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}FNR%2==0{for(x in a)$x="-"}7' txt  FS="" OFS="" file
>atac
AT-G-CA-T--AATTCTTTT
>lipa
AT-A-CA-G--AATTCTTTT
```

Comment: @Kent Setting `FS="" OFS=""` between the file names affects which file?

Comment: @IanLiuRodrigues the later one. you can build some tests to find out.